# abort `wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local` callback externally

Tags: rust, callback, single-page-application, wasm-bindgen, yew

I am building a Yew manga reader application. The home page is a bookshelf that contains thumbnails, and clicking on the thumbnails brings me to a page rendering the pages of the book.

```rust
fn switch(routes: Route) -> Html {
    match routes {
        Route::Home => html! {
            <>
                <h1>{ "Books" }</h1>
                <BookShelf />
            </>
        },
        Route::BookContent { name } => html! {
            <div>
                <BookContent name={name} />
            </div>
        },
        Route::NotFound => html! { <div>{ "You sure that book exist?" }</div> },
    }
}

#[function_component]
fn App() -> Html {
    html! {
        <HashRouter>
            <Switch<Route> render={switch} />
        </HashRouter>
    }
}
```

The `BookShelf` gets a list of books I have, fetches the thumbnails individually to render in 2 columns.

```rust
#[styled_component]
fn BookShelf() -> Html {
    let books = use_state(|| vec![]);
    {
        let books = books.clone();
        use_effect_with((), move |_| {
            let books = books.clone();
            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                let url = format!("{}/books", BACKEND_URL);
                let fetched_books: Vec<String> = Request::get(&url)
                    .send()
                    .await
                    .unwrap()
                    .json()
                    .await
                    .unwrap();
                books.set(fetched_books);
            });
        })
    }

    html! {
        <>
            {
                for books.chunks(2).map(|books| html! {
                    <div class={css!("display:flex;")}>
                        {
                            books.iter().map(|book| html! {
                                <div class={css!("flex:50%;")}>
                                    <Book name={book.clone()}/>
                                </div>
                            }).collect::<Html>()
                        }
                    </div>
                })
            }
        </>
    }
}
```

The `Book` component actually fetches the thumbnail using `use_effect_with()`. It also switches route to `Route::BookContent` when it is clicked.

`BookContent` is similar to `BookShelf` except it fetches and renders the images in the same column.

The current behaviour of the page is that when I click a thumbnail before all thumbnails are fetched and loaded, it goes to the `BookContent` page, but it waits all the pending thumbnail `GET` requests to complete before fetching the book content.

How can I abort all pending get request after the `Route::Home` component disappears (aka clicking a thumbnail to go to `Route::BookContent`) so that I can immediately start fetching the book content?

### Edit

I just came across [Theo's video "You Need React Query Now More Than Ever"](https://youtu.be/vxkbf5QMA2g?si=dqCksMgLl0xbtgKw), which mentions you can send signal to `useQuery` and abort the query. I am thinking this may be want I need, to early return the callback if route is changed. Probably using a combination of context and  `use_location` / `use_route`?

Comment: `async`/`await` is cooperative so your future will have to support being aborted in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the future that I should be aborting is `gloo_net::http::Request` not `wasm_bindgen_futures::spwan_local` because the wasm future gets dispatched immediately what it is rendered and it is the `Request` that is awaiting. And luckily there is an abort mechanism in `gloo_net::http::Request` by setting `AbortSignal`.

By making use of the fact that `use_effect_with()` [calls its return value to cleanup when a component is destroyed](https://docs.rs/yew/latest/yew/functional/fn.use_effect_with.html#on-destructing-or-last-render), we can abort `Request` when `Image` component gets out of scope.

```rust
use gloo_net::http::Request;
use web_sys::AbortController;

#[derive(Properties, PartialEq)]
struct ImageProperties {
    url: String,
}

#[function_component]
fn Image(props: &ImageProperties) -> Html {
    let image = use_state(|| String::new());
    {
        let image = image.clone();
        let url = props.url.clone();
        let controller = AbortController::new().unwrap();
        let signal = controller.signal();
        use_effect_with((), move |_| {
            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                let res = match Request::get(&url)
                    .abort_signal(Some(&signal))
                    .send()
                    .await
                {
                    Ok(res) => res,
                    _ => return,
                };
                let type_ = res.headers().get("Content-Type").unwrap();
                let bytes = res.binary().await.unwrap();
                let data = b64.encode(bytes);
                image.set(format!("data:{};base64,{}", type_, data));
            });

            move || {
                controller.abort();
            }
        });
    }

    html! {
        <img
            src={(*image).clone()}
            alt={"loading"}
            style="height:auto;width:100%;object-fit:inherit"
        />
    }
}
```

Note that if you renders an image with

```rust
html! {
    html! {
        <img src={url} alt={"loading"}/>
    }
}
```

The `GET` request dispatched by `img` tag won't be aborted even when the component is destroyed.